# Exceptions thrown from the binding type converter

Tags: silverlight, validation

Assume I am doing validation on a text box that is bound to a property. On the setter for the property I might decorate the property with the following

[Regular3xpression("^[0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Must be an integer.")]

However, if the user types in a letter in the textbox, this validation would never happen because you would get an exception from the type converter. In other words, if you had a validation summary connected; it would display an error "Input string was not in a correct format." not the desired "Must be an integer".

Am I missing something? This seems broken, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Is your property type `int`? If so, then what's the point of the validation attribute? I will only forbid negative numbers. If it is `srting`, then there should be no problem.

Comment: As I said - it would display an error "Input string was not in a correct format." not the desired "Must be an integer"